# Подключения Java к MongoDB

Tags: java, база-данных, mongodb

Начал изучать MongoDB. Пытаюсь подключиться к ней с помощью Java.В папке с файлом MongoDBConnect.java и MongoDBConnect.class лежат драйвер  mongodb-driver-3.9.1.jar и файлы mongodb-driver-3.9.1-sources.jar, mongodb-driver-3.9.1-javadoc.jar. 
При компиляции указываю и все проходит норм:

```
 javac -cp mongodb-driver-3.9.1.jar;. MongoDBConnect.java
```

Запускаю с указанием `classpath`  в строке

```
java -cp mongodb-driver-3.9.1.jar;. -cp mongodb-driver-3.9.1-javadoc.jar;. -cp mongodb-driver-3.9.1-sources.jar;. MongoDBConnect
```

Выдает ошибку

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver

Что я делаю неправильно? Код программы ниже

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import java.sql.*;

public class MongoDBConnect{

  public static void main( String args[] ){
    Connection con;
    String DBname ="jdbc:mongo://localhost//test";

  try{   
   Class.forName("mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver"); 
   con = DriverManager.getConnection(DBname);


   System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");

  }catch(Exception e){
    System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы неверно задаете classpath - уберите `-cp mongodb-driver-3.9.1-javadoc.jar;. -cp mongodb-driver-3.9.1-sources.jar;.`
См. [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Comment: Даже убирая все в classpath кроме драйвера -cp mongodb-driver-3.9.1-javadoc.jar;. все равно выдает ошибку

Comment: `-cp mongodb-driver-3.9.1-javadoc.jar` - это не драйвер, это javadocs к нему, вам надо оставить только `-cp mongodb-driver-3.9.1.jar;.`

Comment: простите, я не правильно указал в комментарии. Даже указывая корректно  драйвер выдает такую же ошибку

Comment: а, я понял в чем у вас дело - mongodb-driver-3.9.1.jar не содержит в себе класса mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver, отсюда и ошибка.  
Похоже, вы пытаетесь использовать вот этот драйвер - http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/mongo_jdbc.php, если да - скачайте соответствующий jar и добавьте его в свой classpath

Comment: Использую драйвер прямо с сайта MongoDB.

Comment: А где вы прочитали, что надо использовать mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver?  
Лучше, используйте официальный туториал - https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-mongodb-and-java-part-i